# Tomcat 5.5 https connector vs ldap connection

Tags: ssl, https, ldap, java-6, tomcat5.5

I have an application on Tomcat 5.5 and I defined the following two connectors (one for http connection and one for https connection).

```
<Connector port="48080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" address="0.0.0.0"
    maxThreads="512" minSpareThreads="64" maxSpareThreads="200"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />

<Connector className="org.apache.catalina.connector.http.HttpConnector"
           port="28443"
       maxThreads="512" 
           minProcessors="256" maxProcessors="500"
           enableLookups="true"
           acceptCount="100"
           debug="0"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           allowChunking="false"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="pathOfCertificate"
           keystorePass="password"
           keystoreType="PKCS12" />
```

I developed a secure LDAP connetction and when I comment the https connector (28443) ldap works and, obviously https connection on 28443 port doesn't work. If I decomment the https connector, ldap doesn't work with the following exceptions and, obviously https connection works.

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: ssoha.aosp.bo.it:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:195)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2720)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:296)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:82)
at com.noemalife.logon.api.LDAPSProcessor.verifyLogin(LDAPSProcessor.java:76)
at it.dianoema.dnweb.dnlis.servlets.SLoginLDAP.doPost(SLoginLDAP.java:137)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:881)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:541)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1617)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:414)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:387)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:332)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:190)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsPrfGenerator.expand(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsPrfGenerator.doPRF(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsPrfGenerator.doPRF(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineGenerateKey(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:753)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.calculateKeys(Handshaker.java:716)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:873)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
```

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You developed a secure LDAP connection' how? And what makes you think HTTP has anything to do with LDAP?

Comment: It works correctly when I comment the https connector.

Comment: I tried using Java7 and it works too but I need to use java6

Answer (score 0):

Here the ldap implementation:

```
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");       
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://" + srv + ":"+server_port+"/??base?(objectClass=*)");

    if (authentication == null || authentication.trim().equals(""))
        authentication = "simple";
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

    String keystore = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts";
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);
    String securityPrincipal = null;

    if (this.template == null || this.template.equals(""))
        securityPrincipal = "cn=" + user + "," + this.root;
    else
        securityPrincipal = this.template.replace("${user}", user);

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + this.domain);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=" + user + "," + this.root);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    } ....
```